# Swagger API and interaction with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, swagger

A  product was purchased to enable our users to send/receive SMS over HTTP. Now it's my job to build it into our current CMS platform & database. It's got a swagger API.

Here is the documentation for the specific POST request I am trying to send:
[POST: Send an SMS Message](https://api.kenect.com/swagger-ui.html#/Conversations-v1/sendMessageUsingPOST)

Here is my simple python program to test the functionality. I get a generic 500 internal server error response. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
import requests

API_URL = "https://api.kenect.com/v1/conversations/messages"

headers = {
    'x-api-token': '****************',
    'x-api-key': '*******************',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = {
    'contactPhone': '158572968**',
    'locationId': '2045',
    'messageBody': 'test sms',
    'outgoing': 'true',           
}

r=requests.post(url = API_URL, headers = headers, params = params)

print(r)
```

Comment: There seems to be 2 issues. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be 2 issues:

1. Content type and payload encoding.

   You are using `params` parameter in the `post` method. `params` is used with `get` method for [passing data in the URL's query string](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

   In the `post` method, depending on the required content type, you need to use either `data` parameter to [send form-encoded data](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

   `r=requests.post(url = API_URL, headers = headers, data = params)`

   or `json` parameter to send `application/json` payload:

   `r=requests.post(url = API_URL, headers = headers, json = params)`

   Remove the 'Content-Type' key from your `headers` dictionary. `data` and `json` parameters will set up correct content type automatically.
2. `outgoing` is not a valid request parameter for the `/v1/conversations/messages` resource. This field is from the response object, not the request one. Remove it from your payload.

So to sum up, for form-encoded payload the code should look like this:

```
import requests

API_URL = "https://api.kenect.com/v1/conversations/messages"

headers = {
    'x-api-token': '****************',
    'x-api-key': '*******************',
}

params = {
    'contactPhone': '158572968**',
    'locationId': '2045',
    'messageBody': 'test sms',       
}

r=requests.post(url = API_URL, headers = headers, data = params)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and tip- but still same [500] response... even when using postman!

Comment: Well, it might be a different 500 :) Could you share the contents of the request and response objects to see what’s going on under the hood?

Comment: Working on getting you the actual response printed and saved from the python program sending the request.

When using postman to pass minimum required headers and parameters, the response is "Content type 'application/json' not supported".. however when trying the other content types, none of those seem to work either (same not supported error). Referring to the documentation, the example shows content type "string", but that doesn't make sense to me. The text related content types don't work either. Let me know what you would like to see and I'll send it your way. 
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Oh, I missed the json content type. What happens if you replace `data` param with `json` param: `r=requests.post(url = API_URL, headers = headers, json = params`?

Comment: I'm also working with their support people to try to get this sorted out. They were able to tell me that the correct content type for this request is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"... alas, still does not work in postman with that content type. so would there be an alternate param to use for application/x-www-form-urlencoded that might work?

Comment: Thank you- very well done. I was able to get it working in postman, however not yet in python. To make it work in postman,  It is required that some parameters be passed up in the form-data section (messageBody, locationId). I'm sure some research will lead me in the right direction to make the same correction in the python code.... but you were, overall, correct. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. If you have a working set of headers and payload fields in Postman, they should work in Python Requests as well. You can check the `r.request.headers` and `r.request.body` to verify that what is being sent to the server is what you expect.

Comment: First let me say that I'm a sys admin by trade, not a software dev... so forgive me for all of these questions (i'm learning), but I've been banging my head against the wall wondering why this won't work in my python program... in the comment below is the output when i print request.headers and request.body. Is there something I'm missing here? Any last insights you might bestow upon me? :P
The key to getting it to work in postman was to pass some parameters up in the body -> form-data section. Does this have to be specifically declared in python (the form-data part)?

Comment: {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.21.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-api-token': '1130FxmIcc6uZWcq8OXoCZZPC***ODQo', 'x-api-key': 'pdwz0naW5hyCeG9SyJ3PpnOf26****28', 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Content-Length': '61'}
contactPhone=1585739*3*5&locationId=2045&messageBody=test+sms
<Response [500]>

Comment: Headers and body look good to me. The format of the string in the payload is correct. The only thing I can think about is the content type header. Do you specify it yourself? I guess yes, because it is not capitalized. Could you remove it from the headers and try again? Requests will add it itself. Is there any difference?

Comment: Nope, no difference when I remove the content type header

Comment: So the problem was that I can't pass the data as json, needs to be sent as form data. Thanks again for all of your assistance.